# template class 's non-member template operator overload syntax

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class itemType>
class bNode {   
    using nodeType = bNode<itemType>;
    itemType item;  
public: 
    bNode() = delete;
    bNode(itemType _item) : item(_item) {}
    itemType getItem() { return item; }
    friend const bool operator>(const nodeType& lhs, const nodeType& rhs);
};

template <class itemType>
const bool operator>(const bNode<itemType>& lhs, const bNode<itemType>& rhs) {
    //return (lhs.getItem() > rhs.getItem());
    return true;
}
```

It compiles fine but gives me linking error when I run it from main like this

```
int main()
{
    bItem item1(4);
    bItem item2 ;
    bNode<bItem> node1(item1);
    bNode<bItem> node2(item2);
    bool result = node1 > node2;
}


 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool const __cdecl operator>(class bNode<class bItem> const &,class bNode<class bItem> const &)" (??O@YA?B_NABV?$bNode@VbItem@@@@0@Z) referenced in function _main
    fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

What is the correct syntax and why is it failing?
In general what is the correct way to do the following:

1. declare an operator overload in a templated class.
2. define the operator overload implementation outside of the class.
3. how to use it.

Please show all three steps.
I tried adding static to my functions and other suggestions I found online but always get one error or the other.
template syntax is definitely not intuitive.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. What is "bItem"? This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20778299/501250) answer yours?

Comment: GCC is being [surprisingly helpful](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ej6Tzn) in this case, and tells you to do almost exactly what the answer linked by cdhowie says. Alternatively, you can just define the operator inside of the class (in the friend declaration, just add the body at the end instead of the `;`).